# Python 2.7 doesn't look for .so libs in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH (OpenSUSE 12.1 x64)

Tags: python, ld, cython, opensuse

Got a problem with my project on OpenSUSE 12.1:

somehow it ignores the path to libs provided in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

The structure of calls is as follows:
My python module adds the path to libs to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH,
then imports cython module (interface.so) depending on some other corefuncs.so file.

It worked fine on Ubuntu 11.04.
Now it starts loading the cython module, but then throws an ImportError: corefuncs.so: no such file or directory.

I can solve the problem by modifying /etc/ld.so.conf and running ldconfig, but can not make Python search through $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, modified within a terminal session.

Are there any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use PYTHONPATH instead of LD_LIBRARY_PATH.